# My Java Swing application launches the same window constantly

Tags: java, swing

I have looked around and I have no idea why it launches a bunch of windows constantly. I haven't found any other posts like this with my exact problem but if there is let me know. I am also very new to java and after watching a video I decided to try to make some simple game with a bit of my own code so it might be a bit messy if so my apology's.

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    // Game Variables
    Enemies newEnemy = new Enemies();
    String enemy;
    static int enemyHealth;
    static int enemyAttackDamage;
    static String imput = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Game();

    }

    public Game() {
        // System Variables
        boolean running = true;
        JTextField textField1;
        JTextArea textArea1;

        // GUI Variables
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(900, 600);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Dungeon Drivers Alpha 0.2.3");

        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

        textArea1 = new JTextArea(33, 80);
        textArea1.setText("Window launch was Successful.\n");
        textArea1.setEditable(false);
        textArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        thePanel.add(textArea1);

        JScrollPane scrollbar1 = new JScrollPane(textArea1,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        thePanel.add(scrollbar1);

        textField1 = new JTextField("", 80);
        textField1.setText("Enter Text...");
        thePanel.add(textField1);

        this.add(thePanel);
        this.setVisible(true);

        // System Objects
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Player Variables
        int health = 100;
        int attackDamage = 50;
        int numHealthPotions = 5;
        int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
        int healthPotionDropChance = 25; // Percentage

        // GAME
        textArea1.append("\tWelcome to the Dungeon!"); // THIS IS THE LAST
                                                       // MESSAGE SEEN THEN IT
                                                       // CONTINUES TO OPEN
                                                       // WINDOWS
        newEnemy.getEnemy();
        FIGHT: while (running) {

            textArea1.append("\n\t-------------------------------------\n");
            textArea1.append("\t# A " + enemy + " has appeared! #");

            while (enemyHealth > 1) {
                textArea1.append("\n\tHealth: " + health);
                textArea1.append("\t" + enemy + "'s Health: " + enemyHealth);
                textArea1.append("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
                textArea1.append("\t1. Attack!");
                textArea1.append("\t2. Drink Health Potion!");
                textArea1.append("\t3. Run!\n");

                while (running) {
                    textField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            imput = textField1.getText();
                            textField1.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                    if (imput.equals("1")) {
                        int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                        int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

                        enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                        health -= damageTaken;

                        if (enemyHealth < 1) {
                            textArea1.setText("");
                        }
                        textArea1.setText("");

                        textArea1.append(
                                "\t> You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " Damage.");
                        textArea1.append("\n\t> You recieve " + damageTaken + " in retaliation!");

                        if (health < 1) {
                            textArea1.append("You have no Health left so you ran away.");
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    } else if (imput.equals("2")) {
                        if (numHealthPotions > 0) {
                            health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                            numHealthPotions--;
                            textArea1.append("\t> You Drink a health potion for "
                                    + healthPotionHealAmount + "." + "\n\t> You now have " + health
                                    + " Health." + "\n\t> You have " + numHealthPotions
                                    + " Health Potions left.\n");
                            imput = "";
                        } else {
                            textArea1.append(
                                    "\t> You have no Health Potions left! Kill enemies to get them.");
                            imput = "";
                        }
                    } else if (imput.equals("3")) {
                        textArea1.setText(null);
                        textArea1.append("\tYou run from the " + enemy + "!");
                        imput = "";
                        continue FIGHT;
                    }
                    imput = "";
                }
                imput = "";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The other file is named Enemies and here is that code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Enemies {

public void getEnemy() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] list = {"Skeleton", "Zombie"};
    Game game = new Game();

    String enemies = list[rand.nextInt(list.length)];
    if(enemies.equals("Skeleton")) {
        int maxHealth = 30;
        int minHealth = 25;
        Game.enemyHealth = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minHealth, maxHealth + 1);
        int maxAttackDamage = 15;
        int minAttackDamage = 10;
        Game.enemyAttackDamage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minAttackDamage, maxAttackDamage + 1);
        game.enemy = enemies;
    }
    else if(enemies.equals("Zombie")) {
        int maxHealth = 40;
        int minHealth = 30;
        Game.enemyHealth = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minHealth, maxHealth + 1);
        int maxAttackDamage = 20;
        int minAttackDamage = 15;
        Game.enemyAttackDamage = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minAttackDamage, maxAttackDamage + 1);
        game.enemy = enemies;
    }
}
}
```

The final file is called Items and heres that code:

```
public class Items {
static int healthPotion;
static int ironShard;
static int sharpWoodenSword;
static int averageWoodenSword;
static int dullWoodenSword;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not show the reason for your seeing multiple windows being launched, but it does show other significant problems. For one thing none of the while loops should be present as they are completely contrary to event-driven coding practices. Your first job should be to get completely rid of them, and instead write your code to react to events.

Comment: If you still need help with the window issue, then you will want to strive to create and post a valid [mcve], a **small**, minimal in fact, program that we can compile and run unchanged, that has no outside dependencies (such as database or images) and that directly demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will rewrite the code using events rather than while loops. Also next time I will make sure that if I have a problem to make it accessible and usable by anyone.

Comment: Given your code comment, `"THIS IS THE LAST MESSAGE SEEN THEN IT CONTINUES TO OPEN WINDOWS"`, I suspect that you have a problem here: `newEnemy.getEnemy();`, in code that we can't see. I'm afraid that after review of your code, I don't see how it is answerable without guessing, unless you can in fact improve it with a valid MCVE.

Comment: Regarding your comment -- you're going to have to make it accessible **this** time if you want an answer.

Comment: I will just rewrite as I had a feeling that the while was the problem.  Is it possible to just delete this post then after rewriting (Because that will take some time) if the problem continues I make a new post with completely different code including everything?

Comment: I have added all the info needed I believe

Comment: Please, don't use LABELS:, spend some time to consider your problem and design an appropriate solution around it, it's not 1980, we don't need goto's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## That's your problem

In your Enemy class in this method:

```
getEnemy()
```

creates a new Game object.

So in doing this new Game object will create a new Enemy object that will create a new Game object that will create a new Enemy object.... forever.

If so, the solution is not to do this, but instead to pass the current Game instance **into** the Enemy class rather than create a new Game instance.

Change Enemies so that it gets the single valid Game object if it nees it. Change this:

```
public class Enemies {

    public void getEnemy() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] list = {"Skeleton", "Zombie"};
        Game game = new Game();
```

to this:

```
public class Enemies {
    private Game game; // variable to hold Game reference:

    public Enemies(Game game) {
        this.game = game; // set the instance
    }

    public void getEnemy() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] list = {"Skeleton", "Zombie"};
        // Game game = new Game();     // no longer need this
```

Then when you create Enemies, pass in the `this` Game instance:

```
Enemies newEnemy = new Enemies(this);
```

Also as mentioned in comments, the while loops should be present as they are completely contrary to event-driven coding practices. Your first job should be to get completely rid of them, and instead write your code to react to events.

Comment: Thank you very very much xD